# Nest performance issue

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I'm upgrading elasticsearch from 1.6 to 2.3.1 (includes Nest upgrade from 1.6.1 to 2.3.1).

I'm facing a severe performance degradation in aggregation requests.
In order to verify it, i have created a console application to compare between the versions.

The performance of Nest 2.3.1 (elastic 2.3.1) is slower by about 100% than 1.6.1 (elastic 1.6). (30 sec to 59 sec)

Then, I have tested the same query directly on elastic 1.6 and 2.3.1 (with Sense) - the performance was similar.

Therefore, as i see it - there is a severe performance issue in Nest (i have tested the most of 2.X Nest versions)

I'm attaching the console application code, i would like to hear your comments:

```
        var startTime = DateTime.Now;
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            var result = client.Search<obj>(s => s.Aggregations(x => x.Terms("test", 
                t => t.Field(f => f.TagNames))
                .Terms("test1", t => t.Field(f => f.Sellers))
                .Terms("test2", t => t.Field(f => f.Manufacturer))
                .Terms("test3", t => t.Field(f => f.TestProductName))
                .Terms("test4", t => t.Field(f => f.GeneralSearchField))
                .Terms("test5", t => t.Field(f => f.ProductName))
                ));

            System.Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
        var endTime = DateTime.Now;
```

Comment: Would you mind opening an issue on https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/issues? Would like to investigate this

Comment: I have opened an issue https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/issues/2104